# How to search the value and update / add it some values in Nested Array Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, search

Find the value in nested array using Javascript and add or update the relevant array with the following information.
Search `id:jkl` and Add the following keys & values in relevant array `{values:123,field:'Field Name'}` .

**Nested Array**

```
[{
    id: "abc",
    name: "Parent Object",
    children: [{
        id: "def",
        name: "Child 1 Object",
        parentId: "abc",
        children: [{
            id: "ghi",
            name: "Child 2 Object",
            parentId: "def",
            children: [{
                id: "jkl",
                name: "Child 3 Object",
                parentId: "ghi",

            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a recursive function.

```js
const data = [{
    id: "abc",
    name: "Parent Object",
    children: [{
        id: "def",
        name: "Child 1 Object",
        parentId: "abc",
        children: [{
            id: "ghi",
            name: "Child 2 Object",
            parentId: "def",
            children: [{
                id: "jkl",
                name: "Child 3 Object",
                parentId: "ghi",

            }]
        }]
    }]
}]

function findNested (arr, id) {
  for (let item of arr) {
    if (item.id === id) return item // item found, return the current obj
    if (item.children instanceof Array) {
      // magic happens here
      return findNested(item.children, id)
    }
  }
  return null // nothing found
}

const obj = findNested(data, 'jkl')
// obj is a reference here. Changing it will also change the object in `data`
obj.values = 123

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a recursive function to achieve that:

```js
const arr = [{ id: "abc", name: "Parent Object", children: [{ id: "def", name: "Child 1 Object", parentId: "abc", children: [{ id: "ghi", name: "Child 2 Object", parentId: "def", children: [{ id: "jkl", name: "Child 3 Object", parentId: "ghi", }] }] }]}];

const getUpdated=(arr,obj, id)=>{
    return arr.map(k=> k.id == id ? ({...k, ...obj}) : ({...k, children: k.children ? getUpdated(k.children, obj, id) : []}))
};

console.log(getUpdated(arr, {values:123,field:'Field Name'}, 'jkl')); // updated array returned
```